# Error: Unable to log in on Installation IBM Cloud Pak for Application 4.1 on OCP 4.3

Tags: websphere, kabanero

When i run installing icpa 4.1.1 got error like image below ?

[image: Commands and Error I Got This]

Before That i Have Been Logging in on Cluster Using Command `oc login .....`

I Have been Following Procedure in [IBM Cloud Paks for Application 4.1 - Installation Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCSJL_4.1.x/install-cli-windows.html) But Got error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that I have to export a couple of additional variables before running the `docker` command, because the container doesn't recognize the login I've done from my shell:

```
export OPENSHIFT_TOKEN=xxxyyyzzz
export OPENSHIFT_URL=https://your.hostname.com:6443
```

You can get the token (xxxyyyzzz) by running this after you log in:

```
oc whoami -t
```

Then re-run the `docker` command, using `-e` to pass OPENSHIFT_TOKEN and OPENSHIFT_URL.

Comment: Hi Thank You Very Much... Solved